# Weird array behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a tool for visualizing the bubble sort algorithm.

The array `arr` holding all the values, that is to be sorted, is a global variable. The user clicks the "Fill" button `btnFill` to fill the array with unsorted, random numbers using the `fillArray` function. The function returns an array of objects: `{val: x, col: "y"}` where x is the value and col is a color class used for CSS.

When the array is filled, if the user clicks the "sort" button `btnSort`, the `bubbleSort` function is invoked where I guess my problem is:

This function saves a copy of the array `arr` on every iteration of the inner loop. This is an idea that I had since I was having a lot of issues using setInterval to animate - I could just save snapshots of the array during every stage of the sorting, and then pass it to the draw function so that there wouldn't be any JavaScript weirdness combining loops and intervals.

The function finishes running and is expected (by me at least) to return an array filled with copies of the `arr` array from every loop iteration.

The actual behavior which I have tried to understand for hours is that the `snapShot` array is filled with arrays of a **sorted** `arr`. All elements are the same - sorted arrays. Doesn't make sense to me since when debugging it comes out as sorted in console.log when it enters the sorting loop for the first time.

I appreciate any help greatly, thank you!

--EDIT--
I'm aware that the snapShot array gets sent as an array of arrays and will not be drawn to the screen but the problem is somewhere before that. That part was changed for debugging reasons

```
const btnFill = document.querySelector("#btnFill");
const btnSort = document.querySelector("#btnSort");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

let arr = [];

btnFill.addEventListener("click", function () {
  arr = fillArray();
  draw(arr);
});

btnSort.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let sorted = bubbleSort();
  draw(sorted);
});

function bubbleSort() {
  let snapShots = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j].val > arr[j + 1].val) {
        let tmp = arr[j].val;
        arr[j].val = arr[j + 1].val;
        arr[j + 1].val = tmp;
        snapShots.push([...arr]);
      }
    }
  }
  return snapShots;
}

function fillArray() {
  const tmp = [];
  const len = 50;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tmp[i] = { val: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1), col: "red" };
  }
  return tmp;
}

function draw(array) {
  container.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.style.height = array[i].val + "%";
    tmp.classList.add("bar", array[i].col);
    container.appendChild(tmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: `bubbleSort()` mutates the order of the `arr`. This `arr[j].val = ` is changing the original unsorted array into the sorted array.

Comment: The real problem contrary to the assertion of @RandyCasburn is that `bubbleSort()` _is not_ mutating the order of `arr` (generally the entire point of a sort). It's only mutating each element while leaving them all in their original positions.

Comment: @moreOn - please validate your assertions before challenging others. Please take a look at this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/ropoyahoxe/edit?js,console) that has the salient parts of the OP's code. In it you will find the first three elements `arr` before the sort, `sorted`'s first three elements, and `arr`'s first three elements after the sort. You _will_ see that `arr` is in the exactly the same order as `sorted`.

Comment: And this is a minor modification of that showing exactly what I'm saying. The objects didn't move anywhere in the array: https://jsbin.com/citijokobi/edit?js,console - they were each just mutated in place without changing position. -- or another alternative way to show that with even less modification: https://jsbin.com/hanuwekiri/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Agreed - that you now demonstrate my original comment. Thanks for that. Specifically, the end result being the same - the `bubbleSort()` function changes the original `arr` - aka - mutates the original. I do get the reference issue you correctly point out too :-).

Comment: You specifically said "mutates the order of the `arr`" - something that remains unchanged - the order of the elements of `arr` is the same before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it's not working like you want it is because you are doing [shallow copies](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-javascript/) of the array, but the objects in each position are the same references.

This means that this part of the code:

```
    let tmp = arr[j].val;
    arr[j].val = arr[j + 1].val;
    arr[j + 1].val = tmp;
```

Is changing the object that every snapshot element is pointing in the same position. And that's why you get every array sorted, because you are creating new arrays with the same references to the objects.

To get what you want you can do a `deep copy` instead, which also creates new references of the nested values.

```
function bubbleSort() {
  let snapShots = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j].val > arr[j + 1].val) {
        let tmp = arr[j].val;
        arr[j].val = arr[j + 1].val;
        arr[j + 1].val = tmp;
        snapShots.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));
      }
    }
  }
  return snapShots;
}
```

Other solution (and simpler) is to change the position of the object in the array instead of changing the property `val` of the object:

```
function bubbleSort() {
  let snapShots = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j].val > arr[j + 1].val) {
        let tmp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = tmp;
        snapShots.push([...arr]);
      }
    }
  }
  return snapShots;
}
```

Comment: I think preferable to deep copies might just be to actually move the objects around in the arrays. Right now the `val` properties of each object are being changed. I think that something like `let tmp = arr[j]; arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; arr[j + 1] = tmp;` to rearrange the array elements instead of mutating them makes more sense. Then the original snapshot creation should also work.

Comment: You are right, that way works and is simpler, thanks for your input! @moreON